# Replicate rows based on id number in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe (`mydf1`) where the serial number(in serial column) are repeated. I want to replicate the rows in another dataframe (`mydf2`) based on the number of counts those serial appear in mydf1 and get the `result` table. Thank you for your help!

```
mydf1

serial  var1 var2 
   122     a    d    
   222     b    e    
   321     c    f  
   321    fd   fs
   222    bx   eg  

mydf2

serial  varA   varB 
   122    an    ddf    
   222    cb    edf    
   321    ff    ffg  

result

 serial  varA  varB 
    122    an   ddf    
    222    cb   edf 
    222    cb   edf    
    321    ff   ffg 
    321    ff   ffg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm being tricky, using row indexing:

```
`rownames<-`(mydf2,mydf2$serial)[sort(as.character(mydf1$serial)),]
#      serial varA varB
#122      122   an  ddf
#222      222   cb  edf
#222.1    222   cb  edf
#321      321   ff  ffg
#321.1    321   ff  ffg
```

Same result in 2 steps:

```
rownames(mydf2) <- mydf2$serial
mydf2[sort(as.character(mydf1$serial)),]
```

If you want to avoid having any `NA` values for non-matching cases in `mydf1`, then change the middle part of the call to:

```
as.character(mydf1$serial %in% mydf2$serial)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
mydf2[match(mydf1$serial, mydf2$serial), ]
```

This should be robust to `mydf1` containing different or additional values to `mydf2`.

Comment: I might point out, so does the rowname indexing. This is simpler I think, and I think much quicker..... Nicely done.

Comment: @thelatemail, yes, for a second I thought your approach might not be, and then I realized, that it was (and you got my +1 ;))

Comment: I'm still disappointed in R that `match`-ing is quicker than overwriting rownames and then subsetting using an existing variable. I think that `as.character` hurts my answer's timing.

Comment: @thelatemail, the performance of non positive numeric indexing in R is a source of constant consternation for me.  I think character indices are just looked up in a dumb search, so it would make sense for `match` to be faster save for the simplest cases.  The other thing that is maddening is that there is no way to store a hash in base R.  `fastmatch` does it, but with `match` you are left regenerating the hash every time you call `match`, which is infuriating.